# Key binding on Html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do i bind the key W to a button on the webpage

I try to use .keypress but it doesn't seem to work.

Here the code :

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
</head> 
<body> 
    <div class="d-pad">
      <div id="d-up" class="button d up"></div>
      <div id="d-right" class="button d right"></div>
      <div id="d-down" class="button d down"></div>
      <div id="d-left" class="button d left"></div>
    </div>

<script>
 $(document).keypress(function(e){                     // keybiding 
    if (e.which == 87){
        $("#d-up").click(function(){alert('UP')});
    }
 });
</script>     
</body>
</html>
```

I try to bind the key W to the up button with the id = d-up and whenever W is press there will be an alert saying UP. This doesn't seem to work. Did i do something wrong here ?

Thank you

Comment: What is your code snippet doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't say:

> whenever W is pressed, show an alert

You said:

> whenever W is pressed, set things up so that if a div with no content in it is *clicked* with the mouse, show an alert

Get rid of the click handler.

```js
 $(document).keypress(function(e){ 
    if (e.key == 87){
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "black";
    }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note in this demo:

- You need to focus the result to see the effect
- I've switched to using a background colour because `alert` is sandboxed in stackoverflow snippets
- w is not the same as W

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an Event on a condition that will probably never occur. Try this instead:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e){
  if(e.shiftKey && e.keyCode === 87){ // capital W
    alert('UP');
  }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$(document).bind("keydown",function(e) {
        var originator = e.keyCode || e.which;
        if(originator == 87)
         alert('UP');
    });
```